# Is the difference between a loaded elf and libc a constant value?

Tags: linux, exploit-development, aslr

While doing binary exploitation and studying the case when ASLR is enabled, I noticed I could make a reliable exploit by leaking an address of a function in the binary and finding the address of system in libc by adding a constant offset to that function.

So the binary is e.g. loaded at `0xb7719000`, the function is at `0xb7719bc7`.
libc is loaded at `0xb753c000` and system is at `0xb757c190`.

ASLR is enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
```

The binary is compiled as PIE:

```
gdb-peda$ checksec
CANARY    : ENABLED
FORTIFY   : disabled
NX        : ENABLED
PIE       : ENABLED
RELRO     : FULL
```

My question resolves around the fact that I can use a leaked address in the binary to calculate reliably the address of system (which was practical, but I do not understand why).

Is the address difference between libc and the binary always a constant, even when ASLR is enabled and for a PIE executable? One would think intuitively, that both the binary as well as libc would be randomized separataly, and thus have a non constant difference.